# How to add a new page to Joomla Admin panel

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm new to Joomla. I need to add a new custom PHP page inside Joomla admin panel (not on the main site) to display some data from my own tables.
My Joomla version is 3.4.1 Stable.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you expand on what it is you want exactly?  What you would be trying to do with a 'new custom page'?

Do you mean creating a new article via the admin that gets displayed on the site?  Or do you mean a new 'page' that is viewable only when logged in as admin?

Explain a bit further please.

Comment: Sorry. What I mean was. I want to add a new PHP page inside admin panel which will display data from my own tables. And yes it must be viewable only inside admin panel.

Comment: You can't do this. Joomla is an MCV powered CMS, which uses components to display content in the main section of both the frontend and backend of the site. You will either need to create a small component or you could always import the Joomla API (in your PHP file), connect to the database and get the data you want. Then simply view the page in your browser using `www.example.com/myfile.php`. I would of course check for super user permissions in the PHP file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *might* be able to inject a single page to display the data - but I think more than likely your best bet (to do it properly without hacking stuff) might be to develop a small component to handle it best.

By creating the admin component you can create the page you want and display your data however you decide.

If memory serves me correctly, you can create a folder (say com_mycomponent) and create 'mycomponent.php' in that directory.  Then you add your php code to that page to do whatever you want.  Of course, this is for the most basic - barebones idea.

I will expand because to the best of my understanding we will need an installer to actually 'install' the component (although it's been a while since I've developed heavily in Joomla).  If you don't create the installer I think it will cause errors within the system.

- Create your directory
- Create one or two directories in the directory

  - admin (***required***)
  - site  (*optional*)
- Create 'mycomponent.php' in the admin directory (and site directory if you created one) and write your desired
  code into the admin file (and/or) site file.
- Create 'mycomponent.xml' file in com_mycomponent
- Open 'mycomponent.xml' file and paste the below code

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <extension type="component" version="3.4.0">
  <name>Your Name</name>
  <creationDate>2015-05-13</creationDate>
  <author>You</author>
  <authorEmail>you@example.com</authorEmail>
  <description>My Joomla Component</description>
  <files folder="site">
  <filename>mycomponent.php</filename>
  </files>

  <administration>
  <menu>MyComponent</menu>
  <files folder="admin">
  <filename>mycomponent.php</filename>
  </files>
  </administration>
  </extension>
  ```
- You can remove the following if you did *not* create the 'site' directory:

  ```
  <files folder="site">
  <filename>mycomponent.php</filename>
  </files>
  ```
- Zip All the contents under com_mycomponent lets name it
  com_mycomponent.zip
- Login to your joomla admin and install com_mycomponent (the same way
  you would any extension you download)

After it installs, you can view your page at
http://yoursite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_mycomponent

Comment: Thank you Hanny. It works. Only one thing. According to Joomla forum, <install> is working for older version only. I just needed to replace it with <extension> inside XML file.

Comment: You actually should not need to make the site part if you don't want it, only an admin part is required.

Comment: glad it worked!  I will updated the code for anyone else who sees it.  I will also update it so that you don't have to include the site part.

Comment: It says 'can't find installation package' when trying above steps.

Comment: @twan probably because the answer is over 4 years old at this point and some things have changed.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is create an admin module to display the data. It's a bit quick and dirty but it works. Also there are some extensions in the JED that will let you display data from any table.