# Need help to create component page inside joomla 3.5.1 admin panel

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla

I want to create a basic joomla component for some custom functionalities.
I already followed 
[Create component in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215648/how-to-add-a-new-page-to-joomla-admin-panel)

But its not working for me. Its showing:
Warning: JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file.
Error: Unable to find install package

Please Help me...Thanks

Comment: Where is your xml code? how did you packaged the component. The link given by you is correct. It should work.

Comment: Its not working for me sir..Many times I have tried

Comment: Where is your xml code? Attach it here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0wuIu325OtQQjFUYjJTNlVvc2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please help me sir..This is my college project

Comment: Please check the answer I have given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created xml file with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<install type="component" version="2.5.0">
<name>cust</name>
<creationDate>2016-06-07</creationDate>
<author>cust</author>
<authorEmail>admin@admin.com</authorEmail>
<description>This is bhaskar Page Joomla Component</description>
<files folder="site">
<filename>cust.php</filename>
</files>

<administration>
<menu>Custom Event</menu>
<files folder="admin">
<filename>cust.php</filename>
</files>
</administration>
</install>
```

Whereas it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="component" version="3.5.0">
<name>com_cust</name>
<creationDate>2015-05-13</creationDate>
<author>cust</author>
<authorEmail>admin@admin.com</authorEmail>
<description>This is bhaskar Page Joomla Component</description>
<files folder="site">
<filename>cust.php</filename>
</files>

<administration>
<menu>Custom Event</menu>
<files folder="admin">
<filename>cust.php</filename>
</files>
</administration>
</extension>
```

You have to use "extension" for Joomla 3 xml files instead of "install" which was used till Joomla 2.5.
List of changes made in Joomla from  1.7 to 3.4.7 version is listed here

1. https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_1.7_and_Joomla_Platform_11.2
2. https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_2.5_and_Joomla_Platform_11.4
3. https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2
4. https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Backward_Compatibility_in_Joomla_3.4.7

Comment: @AmitRay I suggest you expand your question by stating the reason for this, i.e. `<install>' was the legacy tag, supported until J2.5, etc, etc...

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni the reason why I didnt gave much explanation because the link he provided in his question had all the explanations but still he was making that small mistake. So I presumed by seeing the solution he will automatically understand the reason for the error.

Comment: @AmitRay I understand that, but still I feel your answer will be more complete by repeating this. The whole purpose of SO, after all, is to provide excellent answers :-=

Comment: @FrancescoAbeni Agreed. Its better to explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit typical to create component by read doc. It need to much effort in component creation. some time i use the below site by which we can create component.

```
https://www.component-creator.com/en/
```

But remember if you want to only create component then it is fine. But for learn you need to read Joomla doc properly.